# FileUpload.HasFile returns "False" for multiple files upload - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, updatepanel

I am using ASP.net FileUpload control to upload multiple files in database.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_div_askQ" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FUQuestionFiles" CssClass="form-control" AllowMultiple="true" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnQSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="ASK QUESTION" OnClick="askQuestion" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnQSave" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In code behind I am using `HasFile` to check if files are present or not.

```
log.Debug("there are file" + FUQuestionFiles.HasFile.ToString());
```

But `HasFile` returns false when more than one file is selected.

**Note: In case where only one file is selected, it returns true.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried looping through posted files, like this?   `foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in FUQuestionFiles.PostedFiles)
       {`

Comment: yes. I tried that to count number of files, but count remains 0

Comment: Works fine, I see all files when testing your code and looping the posted files as @un-lucky suggests.

Comment: How is it not working for me then :( It doesnt enter in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[FileUpload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)** has two different properties for checking if a/any file has uploaded:

**FileUpload.HasFile:**

> Gets a value indicating whether the FileUpload control contains a
>   file.

**FileUpload.HasFiles:**

> Gets a value that indicates whether **any files** have been uploaded.

The best way to check if any files is uploaded is to check both `HasFile` and `HasFiles` together.

```
if(fileUpload1.HasFile || fileUpload1.HasFiles)
    // do some code!
```

**Edit 1:**

Have you tried to add line below in the `Page_Load`?

```
Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
```

**Edit 2:**

> Can you please explain what difference this line of code made?

From this [Forms in HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) draft in W3C:

> The content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is inefficient
>   for sending large quantities of binary data or text containing
>   non-ASCII characters. **The content type "multipart/form-data"** **should be**
>   **used for submitting forms that contain files**, non-ASCII data, and
>   binary data.

If the form contains a `file input` the `enctype` attribute of the form should set to `multipart/form-data`.

I think you faced that problem because you put the `FileUpload` inside the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: both returns false .

Comment: Awesome it worked. thanks. Can you please explain what difference this line of code made?

Comment: @DKR again I made another update, hope it helps you and others.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)